# Coldfusion cfdocument to pdf loses css styling

Tags: html, css, pdf, coldfusion

I am trying to use cfdocument to create a pdf with the same styling as a html page.

If I run the cfm the resulting output ina browser is what I would expect.  Wrapping the same code in a cfdocument tag, set for pdf, losses rounded corners on some divs created using border-radius.

There is also some background color not working that is applied using the mark tag.

All the css is in the cfm file in between the cfdocument tags. I have have even included the html5 doc type as the first row after the opening cfdocument tag.

Any issues with this that I am not aware of and suggestions to get around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cfdocument doesn't fully support CSS, I too have learned this the hard way. [This](http://learncfinaweek.com/week1/cfdocument/) article may be helpful.  It says it only supports CSS1 and CSS2.   In CF11 the new htmltopdf tag is supposed to have better support for styling.

Comment: htmltopdf in CF11 in a 100x improvement over the old version

Comment: Take a look at http://wkhtmltopdf.org/index.html . It is free, easy to use and gets you near pixel-perfect PDFs.

Comment: How can you use with wkhtmltopdf with URL variables? Is it possible?